# Linking between Wordpress heirarchical taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I'm wondering if anybody has advice on best practice for what I'm trying to do.

I'm working on a website for an online magazine, and I want to be able to search by contributors name but also their roles.

EG

parent taxonomy = Contributors
parent taxonomy = Role

So then I can attribute to a post a contributors name, as well a the role they played on the post. Eg photographer, stylist, etc.

I've set up the correct taxonomy groups but I'm not sure how to link between them. Eg if the same person may have contributed to one post as one thing and elsewhere as another, as they will cross over at times.

I then in turn want to be able to browse the website by contributor name, and be able to see every post they have contributed in a custom taxonomy archive. While also being able to search by eg a list of all photographers in alphabetical order.

Or, should the role be non hierarchical and just use tags?

I havn't set up such a custom taxonomy structure before and I'm having a bit of trouble getting my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

Do not limit yourself to one taxonomy. A cleaner approach would be to create one taxonomy PER roles (`reporters`, `blogger`, `photographer` ...), and register contributors as terms under that taxonomy.

```
Reporters (taxonomy)
├── Will Smith (term)
└── Brad Pitt (term)

Bloggers (taxonomy)
├── Scarlett Johansson (term)
└── Nicole Kidman (term)

Photographers (taxonomy)
├── Julia Roberts (term)
└── Tom Hanks (term)
```

You will be able to query it by taxonomy or terms, alphabetically or not, pretty much [whatever](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dm7UBF1OIoA).

Each contributors would have their own taxonomy page template, via `taxonomy-reporters.php`, `taxonomy-bloggers.php` and `taxonomy-photographers.php`. Or even a custom template page for a specific user like so `taxonomy-photographers-julia-roberts.php`. You can refer to the [Wordpress Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) and the [Visual Overview](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/Screenshot-2019-01-23-00.20.04.png).

If you really want to understand how Wordpress works (no pun intended), take the time to read the basics, the Wordpress Template Hierarchy is a great place to start.

And you could even go further by adding custom metadata fields to each taxonomy terms with additional information regarding each contributors, for example their social media links.

Comment: Thankyou! This was helpful. I have somewhat decent understanding of Wordpress, though I havn't previously had to dig so deep into taxonomies in particular.

Question, based on your above tree, say Julia Roberts had also worked as a reporter on one post. Could I query based on one search term (JR) which posts she had done what?

EG show a page for contributor Julia Roberts and show a list for each section so it shows posts where she was reporter, followed by posts she was photographer?

Maybe thats a better way of explaining what I was aiming for

Thanks for detailed answer

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Sorry @AaronVIII didn't noticed the question in the comment. Well a template is just a blank page right. You can create custom queries on it. It doesn't have to display the specific query it was meant to serve. Building around our `taxonomy.php` page we could have a bunch of conditional statement and custom queries ready to display a post from others terms.